# Trying to capitalize multiline string, but not working. any thoughts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, capitalization, capitalize

```
text = '''felt happy because I saw the others were happy 
 and because I knew I should feel happy, 
 but I wasn’t really happy.'''

print(text.capitalize())
```

Only first word getting capitalize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) about `capitalize()`:

> Return a copy of the string with its first character capitalized and
>   the rest lowercased.

The method you are looking for is `title()`, which will capitalize every word. Here is the description from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

> Return a titlecased version of the string where words start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are lowercase.

Here is the result:

```
>>> text = '''felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I wasn’t really happy.'''
>>> print(text.title())

'Felt Happy Because I Saw The Others Were Happy And Because I Knew I Should Feel Happy, But I Wasn’T Really Happy.'
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.capitalize` [is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) to only capitalize the first character of the whole string, and lowercase the rest:

> #### str.capitalize()
>
> > Return a copy of the string with its first character capitalized and the rest lowercased.

If you want to capitalize the first letter of each word (lowercasing the rest), [use `.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title); if you want *every* character to be uppercase, [use `.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper).